# How can I input workbook formula parameter in a worksheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below custom VBA function. And it works on VBA module.

```
Function isWorkbookWorksheetExisting(targetWorkbook As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Boolean
    
    isWorkbookWorksheetExisting = False
    
    For Each sheet In targetWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sheetName = sheet.Name Then
            isWorkbookWorksheetExisting = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sheet
    
End Function
```

However, I don't know how to use it on a worksheet cell as a formula. Since the first parameter type is workbook.

Comment: Would the workbook you're trying to use in the formula be the one you're currently putting the formula in? If so, you can use [optional arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments), if not you'll have to specify how you'd see on passing the name (I'm assuming you don't want to type out the workbooks name entirely every time).

Comment: @Notus_Panda It is a good suggestion on this function. But the issue is that I cannot use it on a cell even I input external workbook like: ```=isWorkbookWorksheetExisting("[another-workbook.xlsx]","test-sheet")```

Comment: Excel spreadsheet functions cannot handle the Workbook type: it is not one of the datatypes that Excel recognizes. You could create a 2nd function that takes a string for the workbook name eg: `udfIsWorkbookWorksheetExisting(workbookName as String, sheetName as String) as Boolean` and within that call the original function having converted the string to a Workbook object.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find a quick way to check if the Variant argument you would pass holds a string or a workbook since it'd throw an error if you would check if it's a string (but then again, maybe using `On Error GoTo` would work if you'd only use one argument) so I put this together:

```
Function isWorkbookWorksheetExisting(sheetName As String, Optional targetWorkbook As Workbook, Optional targetWorkbookStr As String) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    If targetWorkbook Is Nothing And Len(targetWorkbookStr) = 0 Then
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ElseIf targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks(targetWorkbookStr) 'this does assume the workbook is open
    Else
        Set wb = targetWorkbook
    End If
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sheetName = sh.Name Then
            isWorkbookWorksheetExisting = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
    
End Function
```

With uses in formula:
If you want to provide the workbook name

> isWorkbookWorksheetExisting("Sheet1",,"Workbook1")

If you don't want to provide it

> isWorkbookWorksheetExisting("Sheet1")

In VBA

> isWorkbookWorksheetExisting("Sheet1",wbVariable)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the `Workbook` parameter a `Variant` and adding some logic to handle optionally, a `Workbook` object or a Workbook name as `String`.

The function I use for this purpose looks like this:

```vb
Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal wsName As String, _
                       Optional ByVal xlWb As Variant = Nothing) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = False
    
    If VarType(xlWb) = vbString Then
        Set xlWb = Application.Workbooks(xlWb)
    ElseIf VarType(xlWb) <> vbObject Or TypeName(xlWb) <> "Workbook" Then
        If xlWb Is Nothing Then
            Set xlWb = ThisWorkbook
        Else
            Err.Raise 5, "WorksheetExists", _
                "Parameter 'xlWb' must be of type 'Workbook' or 'String'."
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each Worksheet In xlWb.Worksheets
        If Worksheet.Name = wsName Then
            WorksheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Worksheet
End Function
```

If the code resides in the Workbook you are using this function in, then you can call it like this:

```
=WorksheetExists("Sheet1")
```

If you want to check for a Worksheets existence in a different Workbook, call it like this:

```
=WorksheetExists("Sheet1", "Book1.xlsx")
```